# First-In-First-Out (FIFO) using verilog

Tags: memory, cpu, verilog, cpu-architecture, hdl

Hello i really need help with this cuz its driving me crazy im using Spartan 3E and below is the .v file for FIFO and after that .ucf file ... im just wondering why i cant write/read to the memory even though i get no errors when i generate the binary file and program the fpga!!

---

```
module fifo (
  input [3:0] data_in, 
  input clk, rst, rd, wr, 
  output empty, full, 
  output reg [3:0] fifo_cnt,
  output reg [3:0] data_out
); 

reg [3:0] fifo_ram[0:7];
reg [2:0] rd_ptr, wr_ptr;

assign empty = (fifo_cnt==0);
assign full = (fifo_cnt==8);

always @( posedge clk ) 
begin: write
if(wr && !full) fifo_ram[wr_ptr] <= data_in;
else if(wr && rd) fifo_ram[wr_ptr] <= data_in;
end

always @( posedge clk ) 
begin: read
if(rd && !empty)
  data_out <= fifo_ram[rd_ptr];
else if(rd && wr && empty) 
  data_out <= fifo_ram[rd_ptr];
end

always @( posedge clk ) 
begin: pointer
  if( rst ) 
  begin 
    wr_ptr <= 0; 
    rd_ptr <= 0;
  end 
  else 
  begin
    wr_ptr <= ((wr && !full)||(wr && rd)) ? wr_ptr+1 : wr_ptr;
    rd_ptr <= ((rd && !empty)||(wr && rd)) ? rd_ptr+1 : rd_ptr;
  end 
end

always @( posedge clk ) 
begin: count 
  if( rst ) 
    fifo_cnt <= 0;
  else 
  begin
    case ({wr,rd})
      2'b00 : fifo_cnt <= fifo_cnt;
      2'b01 : fifo_cnt <= (fifo_cnt==0) ? 0 : fifo_cnt-1; 
      2'b10 : fifo_cnt <= (fifo_cnt==8) ? 8 : fifo_cnt+1; 
      2'b11 : fifo_cnt <= fifo_cnt;
      default: fifo_cnt <= fifo_cnt;
    endcase 
  end
end


endmodule
```

---

```
# ==== Clock Source ==== 
NET "clk" LOC = "C9" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33; 
NET "clk" PERIOD = 5ns HIGH 40%; 


NET "rst"     LOC "D18" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | PULLDOWN ;  
NET "wr"      LOC "H13" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | PULLDOWN ;  
NET "rd"      LOC "K17" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | PULLDOWN ;


# ==== Slide Switches (SW) ==== 
NET "data_in<0>" LOC = "L13" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | PULLUP ; #// SW1 
NET "data_in<1>" LOC = "L14" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | PULLUP ; #// SW2
NET "data_in<2>" LOC = "H18" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | PULLUP ; #// SW3
NET "data_in<3>" LOC = "N17" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | PULLUP ; #// SW4


# ==== Discrete LEDs (LED) ==== 
NET "data_out<3>" LOC = "F11" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | SLEW = SLOW | DRIVE = 8 ;
NET "data_out<2>" LOC = "E11" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | SLEW = SLOW | DRIVE = 8 ;
NET "data_out<1>" LOC = "E12" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | SLEW = SLOW | DRIVE = 8 ;
NET "data_out<0>" LOC = "F12" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | SLEW = SLOW | DRIVE = 8 ; 

NET "empty"   LOC "E9" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | SLEW = SLOW | DRIVE = 8 ;
NET "full"    LOC "F9" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | SLEW = SLOW | DRIVE = 8 ;
```

Comment: The fifo code looks fine and seems to simulate okay.  I see that you have the data_in bus connected to slide switches and the data_out bus connected to the LEDs.  How are you toggling the rd/wr signals?

Comment: I'm trying to assign rd/wr signals to the push buttons on the spartan 3E which are "K17" and "H13" .... btw i just edited a mistake i had before in the .ucf file i wrote clock instead of clk but anyway still not workin :/

Comment: I'm not familiar with the spartan board you're using.  I assume that the board has a fixed clock and that it is indeed at location "C9"?  Also, are you sure you have the right polarity on the rst/wr/rd signals?

Comment: yeah "C9" its 50MHz clock and the connections for rst/wr/rd signals they seem to be right for me after looking at the Spartan 3E datasheet but not sure tbh why its now working :/ its so frustrating bro!! ... btw do i have to declare the inputs as wires or no need!!?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "i can't read/write"?

Comment: If this works in Simulation but fails on FPGA (Hardware) the question may be better on [ElectronicsSE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Cross posting is ok but add the link in each question to your question on the other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I tried this on a de0-nano board which uses an Altera Cyclone IV part and was able to get it to work, so your logic is good.  The one thing that I did add is an edge detect for the rd and wr signals.

With your current code (and my board) when you depress a switch I was getting many contiguous reads or writes.  So a single press of the wr switch would fill the fifo and a single press of the read switch would empty the fifo.

I renamed your rd input signal to rd_in and the wr signal to wr_in and added the following code:

```
always @( posedge clk ) 
begin: edge_detect
  rd_in_d <= rd_in;
  wr_in_d <= wr_in;

  rd = (rd_in && !rd_in_d);
  wr = (wr_in && !wr_in_d);
end
```

which will give you a single rd/wr pulse only when a rising edge of the rd_in or wr_in signals is detected.

Make sure that your switch signals are low when the switch is not depressed as it appears you're assuming.  On my board the switch inputs are always high (pull-up resistors) and only go low when the switch is depressed.  Since a press of the switch creates a logic low condition I had to invert the rd/wr signals to get them to work correctly with your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: rd_in_d, wr_in_d, rd, and wr are declared as reg right!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.  Trying to get something working on the actual hardware can be daunting the first time since there are some many places things can go wrong.  Be sure to check this question as answered if it works for you so that others that browse the questions will know it's answered.